# png on a window form button is not visible at run-time

Tags: c#, winforms, png, background-image

I am facing a weird issue while trying to create a window form button with a backgroundimage set to a png file. I have created the png picture through a glass button generator online. I am not sure maybe I am missing to set a property on the button properties.
I am generating the glass button png file through http://dabuttonfactory.com.
I am setting the BackgroundImage of the button in design mode and I can see the image properly. The problem is at run time.

EDIT:
I tried to copy the code from the designer to show you the code but I couldn't find the printButton control I added. After some deletion  of the controls on my form, I was able to display the button.
But then, instead of putting a button on the form, I put a picturebox and set the image to the png file and again I cannot see the picturebox control in the designer.

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip statusStrip1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel UserInfoTSSL;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel ConnectionModeTSSL;
    private System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer splitContainer1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
```

Comment: Give your form definition

Comment: Try using the image property maybe. Further you can try to set the border of none. For more information show us your form code please. Are you using native Winforms? External Frameworks like DevExpress or something often get LookAndFeel Settings, which overwrite your configuration maybe.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Visual Studio 2015 bug. I had reopen my solution, now it works fine.
I though it was related to the generated png file but it is not.

Comment: I'm just trying to add a png via the Image property of the basic button. Doesn't work for me (in 2019) unless I use an image list. I don't think I will ever know why Microsoft has to make even the simplest things way overcomplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set bgimage layout Stretch mode /zoom mode

Or try to put file in Application resource some time it may not able to retrieve  the image file path